# Set Value of Element Created After Dom Is Loaded in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

action.js

```
document.getElementById("fillForm").addEventListener("click", function () {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: "injector.js",
  });
});
```

injector.js

```
document.getElementById("thisElementWasCreatedAfterDomLoaded").value = "test";
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html,
      body {
        height: 200px;
        width: 400px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Chrome extension demo</h1>

    <button id="fillForm">Fill form</button>
    <script src="action.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

manifest.json

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Demo chrome extension",
  "description": "A demonstration of a bespoke chrome extension being used to populate form fields",
  "homepage_url": "http://www.mwtestconsultancy.co.uk",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Click here!",
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

I'm trying to fill input fields in a web-app that generates dom elements after the initial load. I can access dom elements from the initial page load, but anything generated after gives me an error. I verified that the code works fine via the console - but the extension doesn't find the element and I'm not sure why. Can you only work with elements generated on page load?
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Comment: Sounds like the page doesn't contain this id *at the time the script runs*. To see what's present you can open devtools of the web page and add `debugger;` to the start of injector.js. When it runs the debugger will activate and you can inspect DOM of the web page in its actual state.

Comment: the element is present when the button to run the script is clicked
i can take the same line and put it into the console and it works fine.

Comment: In that case I guess you look at an old error on chrome://extensions page. There's a button to clear the errors.

Comment: Another possibility is that the element is inside an iframe so when you run the code in console look at the context switcher - whether it says `top` or something else.

Comment: its an iframe you are correct

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the element is inside an iframe.

You can run the code in all frames:

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
  file: 'injector.js',
  allFrames: true,
});
```

injector.js needs a check if the element exists first:

```js
{
  const el = document.getElementById('foo');
  if (el) el.value = 'test';
}
```